# Как реализовать динамическое добавление нескольких custom UIView в UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview

Как сделать динамическое наполнение UITableViewCell?

Мне нужно сделать разметку представленную на картинке.
Данные о том какие поля должны быть (ресурс, статус, описание и т.п.) + их значения приходят с сервера. Если поле есть - добавляем его в cell, если поля, например "Описание" нет, то не добавляем поле "Описание".
Количество полей может быть различным.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я создал Xib и класс TableItemView (UIView) к нему. В Xib находится контейнер (UIView) и два UILabel с Contraints.

В цикле по массиву с объектами (полученном из JSON) хотел инициализировать TableItemView и добавлять его в Cell, если в полученном из JSON массиве встречается соответствующее поле. Но тогда не понимаю, какие constraints добавлять к каждому новому TableItemView?

Прошу хотя бы кратко описать алгоритм, как решаются такие задачи.

```
let resourceView: TableItemView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("TableItemView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! TableItemView
resourceView.titleLabel.text = "Ресурс"
resourceView.descLabel.text = "Вода холодная"
cell.addSubview(resourceView)
addTopConstraint(resourceView, toView: cell.subviews[0].subviews[i], constant: 16)
addTrailingConstraint(resourceView, toView: cell.subviews[i], constant: 16)
addLeadingConstraint(resourceView, toView: cell.subviews[i], constant: 16)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Могу предложить Вам использовать `UIStackView`. Дабавьте его в ячейку, задав нужные `сonstraints` ко всем сторонам ячейки. Далее в таблице указываете `estimatedRowHeight` и тогда после получения значений из JSON, если значение есть, создаете `lable` и добавляете его в `stack` как `arrangedSubview`.

Comment: Добавление в cell.stackView сделал внутри метода tableView: cellForRowAt. Но возникла проблема - при скроле таблицы ячейки начинают снова обновляться и в их stackView добавляются еще значения (дубликаты). Не пойму, почему так происходит. Метод reloadData вызывается только после прихода данных с сервера во viewDidLoad.

Comment: Вот пример, здесь такая же проблема - при резком скролле вверх/вниз cell'ы обновляются и в stackView добавляется все больше и больше subviews. github.com/yzhong52/AutosizeStackview

Comment: Так происходит потому, что таблица переиспользует ячейки. Создайте новый вопрос, и добавьте код, там и посмотрим, что происходит.

Comment: добавил новый вопрос. Посмотрите пожалуйста: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/816426/Как-решить-проблему-повторного-обновления-ячеек-таблицы-при-скроле