# Как решить проблему повторного обновления ячеек таблицы при скроле?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, scrollview

Разметка довольно простая - в customCell таблицы добавлен UIStackView и притянут к констраинтами к краям ячейки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В коде в методе UITableViewDataSource: cellForRowAt мне необходимо добавлять в stackView расположенный в cell дополнительный UILabel (subview) при определенном условии.

```
import UIKit

class TableviewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var stackView: UIStackView!
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableviewCell", for: indexPath) as! TableviewCell
    for i in 1...indexPath.row + 1 {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Row \(indexPath.row), Label \(i)"
        cell.stackView.addArrangedSubview(label)
    }
    return cell
}
}
```

Проблема - при резком скролле вверх/вниз cell'ы обновляются (вызывается метод cellForRowAt) и в stackView добавляется все больше и больше subviews, т.е. лейблов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тестовый проект и код: https://github.com/AdilisIV/AutosizeStackview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что ячейка переиспользуется и туда добавляются новые label.

```
tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:_)
```

Таблица берет уже созданную ячейку и вы добавляете туда новый `label`.
Перед добавлением новых лейблов, надо удалить предыдущие. Что-то в этом роде:

```
for view in cell.stack.arrangedSubviews {
    cell.stack.removeArrangedSubview(view)
    view.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Comment: получается так: https://yadi.sk/i/uLgV6vcg3UZuJw

Comment: Исправил ответ.